# Query field text which is part from a longer text

Tags: sqlite, select

I have a table with a productName and PrductID

```
ProductName |  ProductID
   A        |  1  
   B        |   3
   C        |   7
   D        |  8
```

I have a text string with product list string = "1,8,7". I need a SQLITE search statement that will return  records that has productID 1 ,8 and 7 , ie will return records A,C,D.

Comment: Show your table structure and data

Comment: ProductName is text filed NVARCHAR(60)  and ProductID is Integer

Comment: Data is already into the question description. Thanks for support

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op).

Comment: can you give example pls

Comment: I need an example , eg Select * from TABLE WHERE "1,8,7".CONTAINS ProductID.

Comment: I know can use select  command and search for each items "SELECT * from TABLE Where ProductID='1'  OR ProductID='8' OR ProductID='7'"                but the issue is that i have a string that contains > 5000 items , and i can not search for them all as the SQL Statement has limitation. I can also go through LOOP  to search for each item individually, but this takes much time.

Comment: You may use 'like' operator

Comment: i can not use like , because if i use like " Like %1,7,8% it will not return any record because I need to search for records that contains 1 , or  7 or 8 ,  , not "1,7,8". What i do is to split the string 1,7,8 by the comma , then use Loop to search for each . but this is time consuming. I need to return records that contains 1 and that record that contains 7 and the record that contains 8 by single query statement.

Comment: i managed it. I used the IN clause. it works great, and have no limitation to the SQL statement length.